# Error message beside textbox onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, onkeyup

I have textboxes that I want to show the error prompt beside it onkeyup event, but with no luck, it doesn't work. I have this as my reference: [I want to show error message beside my textbox rather than alert in onkeyup event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861900/i-want-to-show-error-message-beside-my-textbox-rather-than-alert-in-onkeyup-even)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#name").next('span').hide();
  $("#name").keyup(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var span = $(this).next('span');

    if (name == "") {
      span.text("Please enter your name").show();
      return;
    }
    span.text('').hide();
  });

  $("#age").next('span').hide();
  $("#age").keyup(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var span = $(this).next('span');

    if (age == "") {
      span.text("Please enter your age").show();
      return;
    }

    span.text('').hide();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<hr>
<span></span>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" />
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong variable names to check the values of the `name` field and `age` field.

Also, the `span` for the name field is after the `hr` it should be right next to the input field.

Check the snippet below, see the comments added;

Notice the **Regex** `.replace(/\s/g,'')` for removing all whitespace in the if condition.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#name").next('span').hide();
  $("#name").keyup(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var span = $(this).next('span');

    if (input.replace(/\s/g,'') == "") { // wrong variable, name is undefined, should be input, also the regex is for removing all whitespaces;
      span.text("Please enter your name").show();
      return;
    }
    span.text('').hide();
  });

  $("#age").next('span').hide();
  $("#age").keyup(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var span = $(this).next('span');

    if (input.replace(/\s/g,'') == "") { // same here
      span.text("Please enter your age").show();
      return;
    }

    span.text('').hide();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<span></span> <!-- span should be here, before the hr line break -->
<hr>

<input type="text" id="age" name="age" />
<span></span>
```

Comment: My bad. Thanks! This works well. I have another question. How can I have an error message on a blank textbox? @Towkir

Comment: you mean on an input field ?

Comment: This does not show error on pressing space bar in the input

Comment: @brk, right, snippet updated. As the OP didn't require it in the question, didn't add it at the first time. Thanks BTW